# What is a clear definition of vibrons?

Tags: solid-state-physics, definition, vibrations, phonons, quasiparticles

What is a clear definition of [vibrons](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vibron)? 
Vibrons are localized Phonons and I need more information about them. It is somewhat vague to me. Can you give some references, please?

Comment: I've never heard of a vibron before, but a quick search makes me think that a vibron is a vibration in a molecule -- not a bulk material. (Whereas a phonon makes more sense in a bulk material.)

Answer (score 4):

The term *vibron* isn't a standard accepted word in solid state physics. It's simply a synonym of a *phonon*, which was probably coined before *phonon*.

As far as localization is concerned, *phonons* can be localized too. For example, in a crystal lattice, the vibrations can propagate throughout the crystal, or there can be vibrations in only a small *localized* part of the crystal. In both the cases, the resulting vibrational quanta can be called a *phonon*.